# Why does liquid flow along the mug

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, flow, surface-tension

I have been wondering why situation described in the picture below happens
[image: Pouring liquid]

Why does the water/milk or any liquid poured from the mug/bottle flow along the surface of the vessel instead of leaving it and falling.

Comment: Indeed, it is a duplicate (minus the cartoon).

Comment: Yep duplicate, I was looking for the answer before I asked however I must have used wrong search term.

Answer (score 1):

It's a weak bond called a hydrogen bond. 
It bonds to other elements as well.
[image]

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structural_Biochemistry/Chemical_Bonding/Hydrogen_bonds